# Keycloak Authenticator SPI example not working

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

I followed the [walkthrough](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi_walkthrough) for setting up a custom authenticator spi for keycloak (version 4.8.3). I pretty much only use the example code i got from [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/authenticator). I only changed the `pom` so i could compile the project and deploy it with `mvn clean install wildfly:deploy`. And it works ... I can configure the new authentication flow in keycloak, update the Browser Flow and  set the required actions. But if i want to use the new Authentication with my application i get the following message: `Invalid username or password`. And in the console i get the following output:

```
17:12:20,721 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=REFRESH_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, grant_type=refresh_token, client_auth_method=client-secret
17:13:50,514 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-4) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException: authenticator: secret-question-authenticator
        at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:194)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:910)
        at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:779)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.handleBrowserAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:139)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildAuthorizationCodeAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:419)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.process(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:152)
        at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildGet(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:108)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:509)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:399)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:363)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:337)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:132)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:100)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:443)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:139)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:142)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:219)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

17:13:50,523 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-4) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=Test, clientId=test, userId=null, ipAddress=192.168.1.123, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_type=code, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/sso/login, code_id=102f9drs-15d2-4e68-b123-38c092640da7, response_mode=query
```

I looked up the file DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:194 on [github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/d593ac3e6fa28f98c3ea99ada29564791d467731/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java#L194) and it seems to be a RuntimeException:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find factory for AuthenticatorFactory: " + model.getAuthenticator() + " did you forget to declare it in a META-INF/services file?");
```

I dont really know what to do about that. I have the META-INF/services from the example project included.

[image]

any idea what the problem might be here?

## Update:

Here my auth. flow settings:

[image]

Bindings » Browser Flow: is set to test

## Update:

I used something like this for my own authenticator.

```
public class TestAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordForm {

    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
        if (formData.containsKey("cancel")) {
            context.cancelLogin();
            return;
        }
        if (!validateTestForm(context, formData))
            return;

        context.success();
    }

    private boolean validateTestForm(AuthenticationFlowContext context, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData) {
        String username = formData.getFirst(AuthenticationManager.FORM_USERNAME);
        String password = formData.getFirst(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);

        // remove leading and trailing whitespace
        username = username.trim();

        context.getEvent().detail(Details.USERNAME, username);
        context.getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.ATTEMPTED_USERNAME, username);

        if (username == null) {
            context.getEvent().error(Errors.USERNAME_MISSING);
            Response challengeResponse = challenge(context, Messages.INVALID_USER);
            context.failureChallenge(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER, challengeResponse);
            return false;
        }
        UserModel user;
        try {
            // Check if this user exists
            user = KeycloakModelUtils.findUserByNameOrEmail(context.getSession(), context.getRealm(), username);
            if (user != null) {
                // do your own thing here ...
                validateUserAndPassword(context, formData);
            } 
        } catch (ModelDuplicateException mde) {
            ServicesLogger.LOGGER.modelDuplicateException(mde);

            // Could happen during federation import
            if (mde.getDuplicateFieldName() != null && mde.getDuplicateFieldName().equals(UserModel.EMAIL)) {
                setDuplicateUserChallenge(context, Errors.EMAIL_IN_USE, Messages.EMAIL_EXISTS,
                        AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);
            } else {
                setDuplicateUserChallenge(context, Errors.USERNAME_IN_USE, Messages.USERNAME_EXISTS,
                        AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);
            }

            return false;
        }
        if (user == null) {
            testInvalidUser(context, user);
            return false;
        }

        if (!enabledUser(context, user))
            return false;

        context.setUser(user);
        return true;
    }

}

public class TestAuthenticatorFactory implements AuthenticatorFactory, ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "test-authenticator";
    private static final TestAuthenticator SINGLETON = new TestAuthenticator();

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public Authenticator create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return SINGLETON;
    }


    private static AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] REQUIREMENT_CHOICES = {
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.REQUIRED, AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.DISABLED };

    @Override
    public AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] getRequirementChoices() {
        return REQUIREMENT_CHOICES;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserSetupAllowed() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConfigurable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "Help";
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return "Test Authenticator";
    }

    @Override
    public String getReferenceCategory() {
        return PasswordCredentialModel.TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Seem like you are setting you custom flow on `master` realm, DO NOT do that, create a new realm and test it there. Can you also provide your new set auth flow?

Comment: @BlackPearl thank you for your reply. I actually use a new realm. I updated the question

Comment: I see the problem there, in keycloak you have flows, each `flow` is consisted of executions and your `secret questions` is just a execution. You should do `Copy` of the default browser flow and add you execution into it

Comment: As you have now, it just like the first step of the `browser flow` is showing secret questions, but you are not logged in yet, that's why you get `Invalid username or password`

Comment: @BlackPearl ah thank you. Thought it would replace the `Username Password Form`. What do i need to do so it could replace the default login altogether? (Also if you post a answer i will accept it)

Comment: got it (looked at the [UsernamePasswordForm](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/browser/UsernamePasswordForm.java#L38))

Comment: @Yellown could you share the code? I have the same problem and I couldn't solve :(

Comment: @AndrédeMattosFerraz i updated my question

Answer (score 3):

For who wants an example:

https://github.com/mfandre/KeycloakSPI/

This example creates an SPI to user storage... The idea is similar to authenticate the user in LDAP but in this example, we will authenticate in a RestAPI and bring the user to the keycloak!